# Python Pandas merge two data frames on two keys and get totals

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs

| F1_ID | F2_ID | Event_ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b2 | ab4 | 5/12/21 |
| a2 | b3 | ab5 | 5/12/21 |
| b2 | a1 | ab4 | 5/12/21 |
| b3 | a2 | ab5 | 5/12/21 |

the second df has a lot more information on it so I am going to show a filtered version of it.

| F1_ID | Event_Name | F2_ID | Event_ID | Date | stats | amount | F1_str_total | F2_str_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | Test | b2 | ab1 | 5/8/21 | 12 | 41 | 13 | 17 |
| a2 | Test1 | b3 | ab2 | 5/8/21 | 16 | 42 | 12 | 54 |
| b2 | Test | a1 | ab1 | 5/8/21 | -12 | -41 | 0 | 7 |
| b3 | Test1 | a2 | ab2 | 5/8/21 | -16 | -42 | 87 | 97 |

I would like to append the details in df1 to df2 and put `None` in the missing columns but im not sure how to do this.

Expected Output:

| F1_ID | Event_Name | F2_ID | Event_ID | Date | stats | amount | F1_str_total | F2_str_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | Test | b2 | ab1 | 5/8/21 | 12 | 41 | 13 | 17 |
| a2 | Test1 | b3 | ab2 | 5/8/21 | 16 | 42 | 12 | 54 |
| b2 | Test | a1 | ab1 | 5/8/21 | -12 | -41 | 0 | 7 |
| b3 | Test1 | a2 | ab2 | 5/8/21 | -16 | -42 | 87 | 97 |
| a1 | None | b2 | ab4 | 5/12/21 | None | None | None | None |
| a2 | None | b3 | ab5 | 5/12/21 | None | None | None | None |
| b2 | None | a1 | ab4 | 5/12/21 | None | None | None | None |
| b3 | None | a2 | ab% | 5/12/21 | None | None | None | None |

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: updated with an expected output and changed some values because i just copied and pasted values that were all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [pandas.DataFrame.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```py
df2 = df2.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

```
print(df2)

  F1_ID Event_Name F2_ID Event_ID     Date  stats  amount  F1_str_total  \
0    a1       Test    b2      ab1   5/8/21   12.0    41.0          13.0   
1    a2      Test1    b3      ab2   5/8/21   16.0    42.0          12.0   
2    b2       Test    a1      ab1   5/8/21  -12.0   -41.0           0.0   
3    b3      Test1    a2      ab2   5/8/21  -16.0   -42.0          87.0   
4    a1        NaN    b2      ab4  5/12/21    NaN     NaN           NaN   
5    a2        NaN    b3      ab5  5/12/21    NaN     NaN           NaN   
6    b2        NaN    a1      ab4  5/12/21    NaN     NaN           NaN   
7    b3        NaN    a2      ab5  5/12/21    NaN     NaN           NaN   

   F2_str_total  
0          17.0  
1          54.0  
2           7.0  
3          97.0  
4           NaN  
5           NaN  
6           NaN  
7           NaN
```

Or you can use [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the first option .append and it worked as expected.